# Redis Error - Error 11001 connecting to redis:6379

Tags: django, docker, redis

I have a Django project in Docker compose container.
So, when I'm trying to `docker-compose up` - it's all OK. All containers, including Redis is up.

Redis logs

> 2023-02-06 14:48:50 1:M 06 Feb 2023 11:48:50.519 * Ready to accept connections

But when I'm trying to send a POST request to my API from Postman - I'm getting this error.

> File "c:\Users\django_env\Lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 617, in connect
> raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
> redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 11001 connecting to redis:6379. getaddrinfo failed.

Anyone knows how to fix it? I'm working on Windows mashine. Thanks)

My docker-compose file

> https://pastebin.com/n2buBpxH

Comment: Show us your Compose file

Comment: Why are you using the host `redis` for sending requests to Redis? It will be available inside the Docker network, but not outside it. Try using `localhost:6379` instead.